# Unit testing does not get attributes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

I want to test (values that are definitely inside my database (I see these values when i am debugging))
I want to get get a list of strings from an linkedArrayList with a LinkedHashMap inside it (named names in code bellow).

I expect that this is wrong:

```
List<String> names = body.stream().map(e-> e.get("name")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Do you know how I can get my test passed by receiving a list of strings of of the attribute name?

[image: DebugResults]

```
public class FinanceRestControllerTests {
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testGetContracts() {
        ResponseEntity<List> response = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://localhost:5050/finance/rest/contracts", List.class);
        List<Map<String,String>> body = response.getBody();
        System.out.println(body);
        MatcherAssert.assertThat(response.getStatusCodeValue(), Matchers.equalTo(200));
        List<String> names = body.stream().map(e-> e.get("name")).collect(Collectors.toList());
        names.forEach((n) -> System.out.println(n));
        MatcherAssert.assertThat(names, Matchers.containsInAnyOrder("Jen", "Nakzo", "Renes"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `names` currently return for you?

Comment: It returns: null
null
null

Comment: Change `List<Map<String,String>>` to `List<Map<String, Object>>`. Then update the `map` call to use `(String)((Map)e.get("customer")).get("name")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have nested `Map`s. You can solve this by changing `List<Map<String,String>>` to `List<Map<String, Object>>`, then access the `name` key of the `Map` from the `customer` key:

```java
(String)((Map)e.get("customer")).get("name")
```